# HTTP "date" header is missing in UnityWebRequest

Tags: unity-game-engine, http-headers, webrequest

I am working with Unity3d and am trying to send a GET request to an API that requires the Date request header.

However UnityWebRequest does not send it automatically (I have checked with https://requestb.in/) and I cannot set it manually since "date" is one of the protected headers.

```
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get (fullURL);

www.SetRequestHeader("Date", dateTimeString);

yield return www.Send();
```

and I get the following error:

> ArgumentException: Cannot set Request Header Date - name contains illegal characters or is not user-overridable

I am able to communicate with the API successfully if I use the WWW class (which does allow me to set the "date" header manually) but am trying to do the same with the UnityWebRequest since WWW will be deprecated soon.

I tried to use System.Reflection's "InternalSetRequestHeader" (as implemented in https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unitywebrequest-cookies.383530/#post-2621262) as follows:

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo dynMethod = myReq.GetType ().GetMethod ("InternalSetRequestHeader", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

dynMethod.Invoke (myReq, new object[]{"Date", dateTimeString });
```

but then I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot override system-specified headers

So, how can I make sure that the "date" request header is sent?

Is there a solution or do I have to use an object from a different library such as .NET's HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 1):

With UnityWebRequest you can't set custom values fro `Date` field, check [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader.html).

Also, check [RFC 2616, section 4.2](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2), in particular [RFC 2616, section 14.18](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18) about Date header. Also, check [RFC 2616 section  3.3.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1).

Are you sure your `dateTimeString` is in correct format?

Comment: Thanks for the links. The problem is not only that I cannot set a custom value to the `Date` field but that UnityWebRequest does not send that field at all with the request. Having failed to set that field myself, all I am trying to do now is to make UnityWebRequest send it automatically as it does with `host` and other protected fields